# Type of user defined class objects - Python

Tags: oop, python-2.7

I am not very experienced with classes or OOP,
and I'm confused with some of the results I'm getting.

I am trying to use `type()` on a class I have created.

```
    class TestClass:
        pass

    my_class = TestClass()
    print type(my_class)
```

The above code returns

```
    <type: 'instance'>
```

Based on my understanding `my_class` should be initialized as a `TestClass` object.. right? Why isn't the output `TestClass`. Also, if possible, what would I need to change to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes):

> Classes and instances come in two flavors: old-style (or classic) and
>   new-style.
>
> Up to Python 2.1, old-style classes were the only flavour available to
>   the user. The concept of (old-style) class is unrelated to the concept
>   of type: if `x` is an instance of an old-style class, then `x.__class__`
>   designates the class of `x`, but `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`.
>   This reflects the fact that all old-style instances, independently of
>   their class, are implemented with a single built-in type, called
>   instance.

By not inheriting from `object`, you create an old-style class, so `type(my_class)` behaves like it does.

Inherit from `object` and your problems will go away:

```
class TestClass(object):
    pass
```

In Python 3, all classes are new-style classes, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want TestClass to be an object, you have to specify it like so

```
class TestClass(object):
    pass
```